# How to use UTL_file to store file at client

Tags: oracle11g

I want to use plsql installed at a windows client to retrive some pdf file saved as blob at server. I found a tutorial about UTL_FILE but looks like it can only create file at server side, so is it possible to create file at client or is there a way to transfer files from server to client? Can someone give me some suggestion? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

UTL_File has a parameter named "LOCATION".  This is where your files will be written and is called a DIRECTORY.  You should be able to create your own DIRECTORY and point it to a location that can be reached by your Oracle instance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY PDF_Out AS 'C:\Users\Me\PDF_Out';
```

Then replace what you are currently using as the value for "LOCATION" with the name of your new DIRECTORY; in the sample it is called PDF_Out.

You may need to check running services to find out which user is running the Oracle listener and grant that user appropriate read/write privileges to the location defined by your new DIRECTORY.

Comment: So I have to modify the server to have access and authorization  to write at my client right?

Comment: No, either the client must become authorization to fetch files from the Server directory where UTL_FILE wrote it, or you must create a server side process that sends the file, once it is created, to your client. Theoretically it should be possible to map some Network drive, so that it is viewed by both server and client as a shared drive, but how you should ask a network specialist.

Comment: Sounds like you need a DBA to create the directory for you and a network person to manage the privileges on both sides.  My example used C:\ and would be problematic as the server is likely to have that drive mapped too; better to find network location or any location that can be expressed in UNC format.